# rbenv install JRuby 1.7.5+ gives load error: rubygems/security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, ubuntu-12.04, rbenv

I'm running Ubuntu.  Using rbenv to install alternate Ruby versions is working fine. When I try to install JRuby using
rbenv install jruby-1.7.x
it works for 1.7.0 through 1.7.4, but for versions 1.7.5 and above I'm getting errors.  Here's the result:

Last 10 log lines:
jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.0/test/test_rake_win32.rb
jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.0/test/test_thread_history_display.rb
jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.0/test/test_trace_output.rb
jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.0/TODO
jruby-1.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/shared/specifications/rake-10.1.0.gemspec
/tmp/ruby-build.20131203104257.1686/jruby-1.7.8 /tmp/ruby-build.20131203104257.1686 ~
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    load error: rubygems/security -- java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found it; at least everything seems to be working now. After carefully purging and reinstalling java yet again and changing the $JAVA_HOME path to the new one, things seemed to be OK until I started up Webrick and got the error:

OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: Illegal key size: possibly you need to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files for your JRE

Per the instructions at http://deployingjruby.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-run-rails-400rc1-on-jruby.html
I downloaded the unrestricted policy files from Oracle and put them in, restarted Webrick and everything crashed. The log had some familiar errors. It turns out that the unrestricted policy files are different for JDK6 and JDK7. Putting the correct ones in fixed the problem.

I don't want to go through the whole cycle again, but I'm 90% sure that was the problem. I suspect the JRuby versions before 1.7.5 worked because they still required the jruby-openssl gem.